# Why By.Id can't find some elements from web page who had property id and is unique

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have the HTML code:

```
<button type="submit" id="login-signin" class="pure-button puree-button-primary puree-spinner-button" name="verifyPassword" value="Sign in" data-ylk="elm:btn;elmt:next;slk:next"> Sign in </button>
```

I write a test case who checks login to Yahoo mail.

My question is:

Why `driver.findElemnt(By.id("login-signin"))` Can't find this element in DOM.

The only solution is to use xpath selector:

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-signin']"));
```

Fantastic, today with ChromeDriver and selenium 2.47.1 run locally my test is successfully.

I tried on many browsers and I don't know in which browsers I have errors.

Comment: Can you consider sharing the error with us what you are seeing? Thanks

Comment: maybe this element takes a little bit more time to load, have you tried waiting for sufficient time?

Comment: I have implicit wait in my code:driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Comment: Which error you getting. I have tried simple code for yahoo login its working at my end

Comment: Error from Selenium, of course.I think that problem is parent of parents of this tag HTML.

Comment: Place ` Thread.sleep(5000);` before entering password

Comment: is it showing `state element reference error` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error `stale element reference:` while enter password on yahoo site

> ```
> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:
>
> 1. The element has been deleted entirely.
> 2. The element is no longer attached to the DOM.
> ```

Either put some wait using `Thread.sleep(3000)` so it get reattach with DOM

**Note:** This is not recommended

Or Refresh the page to relocate the element using

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

**The Best way to use `FluentWait` to avoid this kind of exception** in following way

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-passwd")));
```

although above 3 things will work.
Try below code, same working fine at my end:

```
    driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login");             
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("abc@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

    //driver.navigate().refresh();
    //Thread.sleep(5000);

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-passwd")));

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason 1:**

Waiting for the element to be loaded. Use

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("login-sigin"))));
```

**Reason 2:**

Check to see if  is in any frame.

If yes use following code:

```
driver.switchTo.frame("frameName");
```

before using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login-sigin"));
```

Hope any one of above solution will work out.

Comment: I have frames, but I don't know how to find name of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look on the HTML code.

Did you copy this from your code? There is a 'n' missing in your id (login-sig**n**in).

Otherwise you could use findElement(By.name/xpath/cssSelector/...) In this special case I would use the element name.

Comment: I modified. Thanks for notice.